# Can a Web store with .eu domain sell products intended only for UK market?

Tags: domains, ecommerce, legal, tld-restrictions

This has nothing to do with Brexit and I am not even sure this is the right place to ask this question. I recently bought an electrical appliance from a Web store with the .eu domain extension, only to realize **after** it arrived that it has a UK power adapter. **Nowhere** on the product page was it mentioned that it was coming with a UK power adapter. After contacting their support about it, they replied that they mention in their Terms & Conditions page that all products are conforming to rules and regulations for the UK market. That page is the only place where they mention this. Their FAQ doesn't mention anything about it.

And my question is, aren't there any legal implications for the products of a Web shop with the .eu domain to conform to EU standards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.eu` is a TLD, it relates to domain names, it has no bearing on services running on top of it, such as websites and even more websites content. The only requirement (see section 1 of https://eurid.eu/media/filer_public/76/48/7648e621-0c5d-4c09-8bde-e5622cb6b23e/registration_policy_en.pdf ) is that the domain name owner has a legal tie with the European Union (+ Norway, Island and Liechtenstein). Things will obviously change with the Brexit, but noone knows for now in what way for `.eu`.

After that, what is done with the domain names such as which services are provided like websites content, depends on all national rules concerned.

I also think that as long as they have clearly said things in their T&C then there is nothing wrong from them.

If you want to be sure, contact `.eu` support: https://eurid.eu/en/about-us/#nav_contact